# to display tree structure output in php of a given recursive query

Tags: php, phpquery

i have to show the output in tree format of this pgsql query

```
WITH RECURSIVE SYSTEM_PARTS("PART","PART_NUM","NODE_ID","PARENT_ID")
            AS
            (
                select p."PART",p."PART_NUM",hd."NODE_ID",hd."PARENT_ID" from relma_hierarchy_data hd
                INNER JOIN relma_part p on p."PART_NUM"=hd."FK_ID"
                where hd."HIERARCHY_ID"=2 and hd."NODE_ID"=16515 and hd."PARENT_ID"=hd."NODE_ID"

                UNION

                select p."PART",p."PART_NUM",hd."NODE_ID",hd."PARENT_ID" from relma_hierarchy_data hd
                INNER JOIN relma_part p on p."PART_NUM"=hd."FK_ID"
                , SYSTEM_PARTS sp
                where hd."HIERARCHY_ID"=2 and  sp."NODE_ID"=hd."PARENT_ID" AND hd."NODE_ID"<>hd."PARENT_ID"

            )
        select * from SYSTEM_PARTS');
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If this is LOINC data, then NODE_ID = PARENT_ID for the root of a tree.

2) Also, the PATH_ENUMERATION (the 'Dewey Decimal Number') of the tree can help with display issues (as in 002.014.003 is the third child of 002.014).